# If a porch doesn't have a roof, would you still call it "porch"?

Tags: word-meaning

Dictionaries say a porch must have a roof.
Does it mean native English speakers never say "porch" if there's no roof or at least some awning above the door?

If, as applied to the following pictures, "porch" is an odd or incorrect word to you, then how would you call it?

Picture #1:
[image]

Picture #2:
[image]

Comment: You might want to do a Google Images search for "porch" to see what people think a porch looks like.  Neither of those looks anything like a porch.

Comment: Picture 1 shows a step; picture 2 steps. I don't think anyone would refer to either as a porch, but particularly not the first one which has absolutely none of the qualities of a porch (not even the slightest wall, pillar, post, fence, or barrier at front or side)

Answer (score 3):

Both pictures are just examples of entryways into a building. Usually people will just say front entrance, back entrance, front door, side door etc.

A porch is usually used to describe the entrance of a house disregarding how covered it is while many use patio in reference to a house’s back door. In contrast, a patio is used in reference to a back exit of a house, but you’ll find many people use whichever one comes to mind. Restaurants also call outdoor seating in a covered or non covered area patio seating.

If instead of a typical concrete area you have an elevated platform made of dimensional lumber then you’ll have a deck.

Although there are some who would be pedantic about the term you use most people don’t bat an eye as long as you clarify which patio, porch, door, or whatever term you use when trying to talk about a wall with a hole covered by a slab of wood. My front porch is a deck. Unfortunately I don’t have a back patio, but some of my neighbors have a back porch. Except the ones that only have a front porch and a balcony.

Comment: +1 Also "stoop" or "front stoop"

Comment: @gotube - you'd get funny looks if you said that in the UK

Answer (score 1):

To me (UK) a porch is a small shelter outside the front door (sometimes a projecting roof with or without sides, sometimes the door is set back from the front wall of the house to leave an alcove that people can stand in). It might even be a little 'room' inside the outer door where people leave boots, umbrellas etc but which is separated from the main house by a locked door.